# Strange Issue with javascript setting the local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I want to set the local storage with unique key with "DONE" value

for example :

PdfSeen as key DONE as value

VideoSeen as key DONE as value

both

```
localStorage.setItem("PdfSeen" , "DONE"); 
localStorage.setItem("VideoSeen" , "DONE");
```

set a new entry in the local storage with

> key DONE and value undefined

my expected result is

> PdfSeen as key DONE as value
>
> VideoSeen as key DONE as value

please check this below image to understand the issue well

the below code leads to the above entry in the localstorage

[image]

Comment: what is the problem you have?

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding your question. Could you please elaborate on what you expect to happen when you run your code and what is actually happening?

Comment: I edited the question , check again @ChrisLi

Comment: Where is the code you're using to try to do this?

Comment: How are you verifying the problem? If you execute `console.log(localStorage.getItem('PdfSeen'))` after your code, you should see `"DONE"` in your console. Is that not the case?

Comment: i still dont understand, are you trying to do localStorage.setItem("DONE" , undefined) ?

Comment: @Phil , can you check the image on the question please = I updated it

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem. Is it the `undefined` showing under `localStorage.setItem("PdfSeen" , "DONE");`? If so, that's just the [return value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem#Return_value) from `setItem()`

Comment: @27mdmo7sn which browser (vendor / version) are you using?

Comment: Chrome Version 68.0.3440 (MAC OS)

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue on my browsers (Ubuntu, FF, Chrome), however, maybe this is really a browser related bug. Can someone with the same OS/Browser reproduce this issue?

Comment: @Jankapunkt You're assuming there is an "issue". OP hasn't provided a [mcve] yet; we don't know why OP thinks anything is wrong.

Comment: How could you prove a hypothetical bug like this using a mcve?

Comment: @Jankapunkt By explaining what you mean by "bug like this". What is the actual issue? There must be some observation where you expect X but see Y, and if so, you have evidence you should post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found your issue. You have to pull down your bar on local storage. See the following images:

[image]

Now use the cursor to drag the line some pixels down and you will see the real keys:

[image]

Comment: If that's the answer, then where did the claim about "*value undefined*" come from? There's no `undefined` anywhere in the screenshot.

Comment: What just happened?

Comment: That was the missing part of OPs uncomplete problem description - OP did not mention that the result is not validated using J's code but visually in a browser tab. OP also confused undefined as return value from the console input with the keys not being shown in the developer tools. Now it is a good example of why mcve is a really important requirement for a good question.

Comment: @melpomene clarified this well in the comments below the question.

Answer (score 1):

`undefined` in the `console` only means, that there was no return value.

```
localStorage.setItem("PdfSeen", "DONE");      // will log `undefined`
console.log(localStorage.getItem("PdfSeen")); // will log the value.
```

also see [Using the Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API).

Comment: If `localStorage.setItem()` doesn't work (highly unlikely), what makes you think anything else will work?

Comment: @Phil `undefined` in the `console` only means, that there was no return value... which might be the reason for the confusion.

Comment: I'm not sure what that has to do with your answer

Comment: @Phil because the image had been added and so the answer had been updated... better down-vote the question, not the answer.

Comment: Nice edit, your answer makes much more sense now. +1

Comment: @Phil console.log(localStorage.getItem("PdfSeen")); => logged null then undefined

Comment: @27mdmo7sn this is not my answer and that code doesn't appear in your question anywhere